# Material-ui autocomplete on enter key press move to next element

Tags: autocomplete, material-ui

The material ui autocomplete is working very nicely for me. I have just one question: when the user presses the enter key on the keyboard, it selects the appropriate entry in the list as expected. Is there a way to move on to the next form element automatically?

Comment: You want to change the focus to another element?

Comment: Are you going to change the focus by following the pressing enter? Or once Enter pressed and it should be automatically changed to the next element?

Comment: Yes, simply put change the focus to the next element, but only after the built-in behaviour of the enter key has selected a list item and finished processing